# how can we get detailed debug statements for perl exe

Tags: perl

One of our application is running using perl v5.16.3 and perl.exe is crashing in Windows environment after application ran successfully for couple of hours. I would like to get the maximum debug statements/details possible for the crash.

Need help on how this can be achieved, basically like we do in gdb for other languages, how can we do it for perl ?

In case of C, like we get the coredump and can get the call stack attaching the dump in GDB, is there a similar way to get a perl coredump or additional logging and check the backtrace ?

**Sample Code for reference :**

```
@echo off

set PERL_EXE=perl
set PERL5LIB=

"%PERL_EXE%" "test.pl" %*
```

Perl application crashed after couple of hours.

Comment: *"... get the coredump and can get the call stack attaching the dump in GDB"*: You could [compile a debugging](https://metacpan.org/release/RJBS/perl-5.36.0/view/INSTALL) version of perl and run your perl script using the mingw gdb.exe that comes included with Strawberry perl

Comment: What do you mean by 'crashing'? Is the perl interpreter SEGVing? Or is the program just exiting when you don't expect it to? Or is it printing some sort of error message? Do you want to debug your perl program or the perl interpreter?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions !!
Perl interpreter is SEGVing and it shows the faulty module name is perl.exe. However it doesn't give more details about why it is giving seg fault. Wanted to check more details around it.